# Netsuite - Pulling Vendor Bill Data with Internal ID from SOAP API Call

Tags: netsuite

Team,

So the whole goal is to get Payment level information done on vendorbill with the use of Internal ID...
I tried with Rest API, SOAP Action as 'Get' in SOAP API Call and none of them were giving Payment level information accurately or no information of payment at all.....My requirement is to pull bill payments((Full or Partial Payments)) done on a vendorbill with the help of Vendorbill Internal ID....

So i tried using SOAP Action as 'search' with below request body and it is failing :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2023_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
xmlns:listRel="urn:relationships_2023_1.lists.webservices.netsuite.com"
xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2023_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
<soapenv:Header>
<platformMsgs:tokenPassport>
<platformMsgs:account>{{ACCOUNT}}</platformMsgs:account>
<platformMsgs:consumerKey>{{CONSUMER_KEY}}</platformMsgs:consumerKey>
<platformMsgs:token>{{TOKEN_ID}}</platformMsgs:token>
<platformMsgs:nonce>{{nonce}}</platformMsgs:nonce>
<platformMsgs:timestamp>{{timestamp}}</platformMsgs:timestamp>
<platformMsgs:signature algorithm="HMAC_SHA256">{{signature}}</platformMsgs:signature>
</platformMsgs:tokenPassport>
<preferences>
<runServerSuiteScriptAndTriggerWorkflows>
false
</runServerSuiteScriptAndTriggerWorkflows>
</preferences>
<searchPreferences>
<pageSize>1000</pageSize>
<bodyFieldsOnly>false</bodyFieldsOnly>
</searchPreferences>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<platformMsgs:search xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<searchRecord xsi:type="VendorBill">
<vendorJoin xsi:type="VendorSearchBasic">
<internalId operator="EQUALTO" xsi:type="platformCore:SearchMultiSelectField">
<platformCore:searchValue>37xxx</platformCore:searchValue>
</internalId>
</vendorJoin>
</searchRecord>
</platformMsgs:search>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried different variations of type as Vendorbill(upper, lower, camel case) and only vendor...none of them are working and Below is the error i got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
<faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid type: VendorBill</faultstring>
<detail>
<ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">partners009</ns1:hostname>
</detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can someone please check and correct me what am i missing in the request body and also let me know if the request body has all relevant information that can give me payments done on that Vendorbill....Thanks in advance....